# Why do I see two lines in fstat for the same socket/port?

Tags: networking, openbsd

Seen on OpenBSD 6.1:

When i do a `fstat | grep internet` on my openbsd server (192.168.102.128), I have the following result :

```
jrx      sshd       87949    3* internet stream tcp 0x0 192.168.102.128:22 <-- 192.168.102.67:63857
root     sshd       69801    3* internet stream tcp 0x0 192.168.102.128:22 <-- 192.168.102.67:63857
_smtpd   smtpd      26906    8* internet6 stream tcp 0x0 [::1]:25
_smtpd   smtpd      26906    9* internet6 stream tcp 0x0 [fe80::1%lo0]:25
_smtpd   smtpd      26906   10* internet stream tcp 0x0 127.0.0.1:25
root     sshd       20185    3* internet stream tcp 0x0 *:22
root     sshd       20185    4* internet6 stream tcp 0x0 *:22
_syslogd syslogd    13823    4* internet dgram udp *:514
_syslogd syslogd    13823    5* internet6 dgram udp *:514
_dhcp    dhclient   62845    3* internet dgram udp *:0
_dhcp    dhclient   62845    9* internet raw ip 0x0
root     dhclient   90416    3* internet dgram udp *:0
```

I have a SSH connection using my account jrx from a host 192.168.102.67, so I understand the first line.

But why are there this second line with the root account doing sshd (as process 69801) from the same socket, and from the same client port ?

Is it a special configuration of my SSH client on the client side ? (I use putty on the client side)

**EDIT** : In [Absolute OpenBSD 2nd Edition](https://books.google.fr/books?id=PN6Xy9zWAbsC&lpg=PA202&vq=fstat&hl=fr&pg=PA202#v=onepage&q&f=false), you only see one connection line, not two.

Comment: sshd runs 2 server processes per connection so it can minimize the amount of work done in the one running as root. This feature is called **privilege separation** (privsep). I can't explain why both processes have the socket open (I would have guessed that the root process would close the socket after handing it to the other process) so I leave that for someone else to complete the answer.

Comment: Exactly: I thought too that the root process would close.

Comment: Do an strace on the process and see exactly what it is doing

Comment: strace is not available under openbsd.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would expect. To listen on a privileged port, a process must be running with root privilege. But once a user is connected, then we want that process to be running with the privileges of the connected user. If the server process simply dropped its privileges then it wouldn't be able to service a request from different user. There is also the problem that the server must handle multiple connections concurrently. So what happens is that the server (running as root) listens on the socket till a user connects, then to both allow it to handle other requests and to run with the right level of privilege, it forks, creating 2 instances. One instance goes back to listening for connections, the other switches to the less privileged user. Both have a copy of the handle referencing the socket connection.

If *either* process closes the socket, then unlike 2 processes talking to the same file, the connection will be lost.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that the second line (process 69801) is not a root process listening to incoming connections. It is a root process connected to 192.168.102.67:63857. The sshd root process listening to incoming connections is process ID 20185 in the table.

Comment: It is a socket handle owned by the root listening process - but its the same handle as pid 87949. Two processes, one socket.